# Android alertdialog how do I prevent the negative button confirm the action once I selected an item from the single choice items

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently I have created the change language inside the alert dialog with `setSingleChoiceItems`, `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton`. How do I prevent the language change if clicked `setNegativeButton`?

```
private fun showChangeLanguageDialog() {

    val listItems = arrayOf(getString(R.string.english), getString(R.string.chinese))
    val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@LoginActivity)
    mBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_language))
    mBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1) { dialogInterface, i ->

        when (i) {
            0 -> {
                setLocale("en")
            }
            1 -> {
                setLocale("zh")
            }

        }}.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_ok)) { dialogInterface, i ->

            recreate()
            dialogInterface.dismiss()

        }.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_no)) { dialogInterface, i -> }

    val mDialog = mBuilder.create()
    mDialog.show()
}
```

Right now the `setPositiveButton` is working correctly and I have `setCancelable` to false, so how do I able to achieve the `setNegativeButton`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you always set the language when selecting each item in the following code:

```
mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1) { dialogInterface, i ->

    when (i) {
        0 -> {
            setLocale("en")
        }
        1 -> {
            setLocale("zh")
        }

    }}
```

So, you need to set the locale only when you click the positive button. This can be achieved by using a temporary variable for your locale. Something like this:

```
private fun showChangeLanguageDialog() {
    ...

    val temporaryLocale = ""

    mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1) { dialogInterface, i ->

        when (i) {
            0 -> {
                temporaryLocale = "en"
            }
            1 -> {
                temporaryLocale = "zh"
            }

        }}.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_ok)) { dialogInterface, i ->

            setLocale(temporaryLocale)
            recreate()
            dialogInterface.dismiss()

        }.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_no)) { dialogInterface, i -> }

    val mDialog = mBuilder.create()
    mDialog.show()
}
```

**Note**: code not yet tested.

Answer (score 0):

You are not performing any action on the negative button click.

Please do as below.

```
.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_no)) { dialogInterface, i->   
 dialogInterface.dismiss(); 
 }
```

Comment: added `dialogInterface.dismiss()` still same